# Android studio sync settings between different computers

Tags: android, android-studio

I use 3 different computers for programming in the android studio.

What is the best way to sync android studio settings between computers?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this by configuring the **Settings Repository** available under the menu **File** > **Settings Repository**.

As per the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html) the settings repository can be either a Github or Bitbucket repository. Though the documentation is for Intellij Idea but the functionality is available in Android Studio as well.

For syncing up your settings via repository, follow the [official instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#settings-repository).

Comment: Heads up for anyone who can't find Settings Repository under the File menu: this feature is now deprecated in favor of Settings Sync. You can still install the deprecated Settings Repository plugin through the plugin manager.

Answer (score 5):

The way I do it is exporting settings from Android Studio into Jar archive.

This Jar can then be imported in another instance of Android Studio, or, even, another instance of IntelliJ platform (which is very convenient if you also work with PyCharm etc.).

Take a look at IntelliJ's official documentation: [Exporting and Importing Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/exporting-and-importing-settings.html)

Comment: I know that and I use it. But the android studio has account and there must be sync between computers with the same account. Also importing jar is not perfect there is problem  with different sdk path, logcat colors etc...